# Issue Understanding Topological Definition of Compact Subspace

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I am agonizing over certain properties of a compact subspace in topology, and I want to see if I have made sense of an issue.

We'll use Rudin's pair of definitions, although any will do:

By an open *cover* of a set $E$ in a metric space $X$ we mean a collection ${G_\alpha}$ of open subsets of $X$ such that $E \subset \bigcup_\alpha \space G_\alpha$.

Also,

A subset $K$ of a  metric space $X$ is  said to be *compact* if every open cover of $K$ contains a *finite* subcover.

More explicitly, the requirement is that if ${G_\alpha}$ is an open cover of $K$, then there are infinitely many indices $\alpha_1$ $,...,$ $\alpha_n$ such that:

$$ K \subset G_{\alpha_1} \cup \cdots \cup G_{\alpha_n}$$

My first impulse to disprove this was to first examine the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$, where our usual definition of a compact space (closed and bounded) is defined. Let's pick two elements from the topology $(\tau)$. Let's choose it to be $\mathbb{R}$ itself, and the empty set $\varnothing$. Let's also choose our $K$ to be $\mathbb{R}$. Now,
$$ (K = \mathbb{R}) \subseteq  ((\mathbb{R} \cup \varnothing) = \mathbb{R})$$
The right hand side fulfills the definition of being a finite union, but $K$ is clearly not bounded.

However, I came to this resolution:

It is true that $\mathbb{R} \subseteq \mathbb{R}. $ However it is false that $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{R}$. Rudin's definition calls for $K$ to be a *proper* subset of the covering, and the real number line is not a proper subset of itself. I would assume similar cases would show that other "unbounded" subspaces would satisfy the topological definition. In other words, $K$ being a *proper* subset of its open cover is essential.

Is this correct?

Comment: You are forgetting the crucial word **every** in the definition of  a compact set.

Comment: It is not correct. $K\subseteq X$ is a compact subspace of $X$ if *every* open cover of $K$ contains a finite subcover of $K$. There is *no* condition that $K$ is a *proper* subset of the union of the covering subsets. If $K$ is not open (which is often but not always the case for compact sets) then automatically $K$ is a proper subset of this union, since the union is an open set.

Comment: It's true that there may be some open covers of $K$ which have a finite subcover, but there are also some that don't, which is the crucial component that makes $K$ non-compact.  For a specific example, we have that $K \subseteq \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} (n,n+2)$, but there is no finite collection of intervals $(n,n+2)$ that cover $K$.

Comment: You have a notational confusion. Rudin is using $\subset$ to mean $\subseteqq$, which is common. Authors who do this will only use $\subsetneqq$ to denote proper subset. There is nothing about $proper$ subsets in the definition of $compact$.

Comment: Ok, then can someone step-by-step give me the criteria from which the subcover is being generated, and what qualifies as finite? Are we generating our covers always from the subsets of $X$ in $(X, \tau)$? Otherwise, (If I'm allowed to choose my subcovers any way I want) couldn't I just make the "finite" union of subcovers for $\mathbb{R}$ be $(\mathbb{R}^- \cup \mathbb{R}^+)$? I would assume then that the unions must use sets in the topology $\tau$ as the basis. I would prefer a good answer that belabors each point, basically the opposite of Rudin.